# How to chop string in SQL

Tags: sql

this is my second week of learning SQL
it might be an easy question

How can I sub string a string in SQL
something like

Robert Miller

should become

Robert
Miller

Thanks for the help

Comment: Although the answers below should give you some guidance, what happens if you have a name like Robert A. Miller, or Pete Hancock Jr.  or Miss Janet Palmer, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although different SQL versions have different string functions, try

```
SUBSTRING(<string>,1,CHARINDEX(' ',<string)-1) + char(13)+char(10)+
RTRIM(SUBSTRING(<string>,CHARINDEX(' ',<string>)+1,99))
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a task for you application code, OR you could store `Robert` and `Miller` in two fields in your DB - `first_name` and `last_name`

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can use a substring function to select the required portion of a string,

For example,

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Last Name],2,4)
FROM AbsenceView
WHERE [Employee ID] = 6425;
```

Here the SUBSTRING function will take the LAST NAME from the view/table AbsenceView according to where condition, and return the substring from the string position 2 to 4.

More SQL string functions [can be found here](http://www.technoreader.com/SQL-Server-String-Functions.aspx) ...

Answer (score 0):

The specifics depend on the SQL server you use, but there's usually a `REPLACE()` function available that will allow you to do this. You would replace spaces with newline characters (`\n`).